# Perforce .net API download file directly from server / connection time out

Tags: c#, .net, timeout, export, perforce

I am building a wrapper for the Perforce .net API and I need to be able to download files from the Depot directly to my computer (not a check out!) as the file will be used in another project!

Currently I have a (quite special) solution where I run the "copy" command without submitting, copies that file to the correct location using the File.Copy function and then reverting the P4 copy. It works, but when the file is too big (~200 mb) I will get this error instead:

[Command time out[655371]: copy //FROM_PATH //TO_PATH]

I noticed that if you right click a file in the P4V you can choose the option "Export to...", I cannot find a command like that using the API or the command line... does anyone know a better way of exporting files than the one I currently use? (it needs to be able to run from a C# application)

Alternatively, if anyone knows how to bypass the Command time out, that would also be great!

Thanks!

***Edit:***

I found the solution to the Command time out:

You can change the delay until a time out occurs by creating a new instance of the TimeSpan class with the desired delay and then assigning it to the CommandTimeout variable of your connection instance (when you have a connection established):

example:
m_connection.CommandTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliseconds);

I am still interested to see if anyone knows a way of exporting files without having to do my strange version!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the 'p4 print -o' command?